# Read binary data written with octave

Tags: c++, octave, binary-data

`a` is a simple `2x`2 matrix in octave. I save it as binary data in `data.bin`:

```
octave:42> save -binary data.bin a
```

Now I would like to open the file and read the data from outside octave. I tried to use `liboctave` (`do_load()` and `read_binary_data()`) following this example (http://wiki.octave.org/Fortran) but without success.

I use

```
do_load (file, fname, format, oct_mach_info::flt_fmt_unknown, false, false, true, argv, 0,` 1, 1);
```

I have an error with `read_binary_data()`

> error: load: trouble reading binary file `data.bin'

The file is ok (I can load it from octave), so I guess I'm doing something wrong.. but what?

Comment: check the file pointer, does it point to an ifstream? is it null?

Comment: also check the filename .. has it got the fullpath?

Comment: I tried to load an ascii file and it works.. This i guess excludes file pointer problems..